# how autofill TikTok country with javascript

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

i need to autofill TikTok country auto.
i can autofill mobile number with js code

```
var el = document.querySelector('input[name="mobile"]');
el.value = Math.floor(
   Math.random() * (96808000 - 96808099) + 96808099 );
```

the problem i cant choose the correct element for country
i try this code but not working.

```
document.querySelector('class[aria-label="tiktok-1k8r40o-DivAreaLabelContainer ewblsjs4"]') = "ET +251 phone country code. Double-tap for more options";
```

pleas how can i do the code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CobIX.png)`